# SQL Query syntax - interlinking table

Tags: sql

Just looking for a bit of help with an SQL query. I've had a bit of a search, but mostly brings up stuff about simpler joins involving two tables.

The table structure is:

**table.Itineraries**

```
ItineraryID, Itinerary, etc
```

**table.Activities**:

```
ActivityID, Activity, etc
```

And an interlinking table

**table.ItineraryActivities**:

```
ItineraryID, ActivityID
```

And I have a page here, listing Itineraries:

http://www.goodsafariguide.net/itineraries_beta/index101.php

That I would like to include some of the Activities on.

If it was just the first two tables, and `tableActivities` had an `ItineraryID` column, I assume it would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Itineraries 
INNER JOIN Activities ON Itineraries.ItineraryID = Activities.ItineraryID
```

But I'm not sure what the syntax would be to achieve the same thing with the interlinking table as well.

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT:

I now have it displaying the Activities (in this case Countries):

http://www.goodsafariguide.net/itineraries_beta/index501.php

So where there are two instances of 'Test Itinerary', one for Tanzania and one for Kenya, I just want one instance, which lists Kenya and Tanzania.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a second `INNER JOIN`.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Itineraries i
INNER JOIN ItineraryActivities ia ON ia.ItineraryID = i.ItineraryID
INNER JOIN Activities a ON a.ActivityID = ia.ActivityID
```

Comment: Thank you. I've got that showing the first result, like this: http://www.goodsafariguide.net/itineraries_beta/index301.php How can I get it to loop through those results nested inside the main table?

Comment: @johngordon - A good place to start is by looking at how [`mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) works. On the documentation page, there is a good [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#80821) of looping through the query results.